# Calculus - Derivatives of Polynomials

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=-3x^2-14x-5$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{15}{2}x+29$ are parabolas on the same grid.

The tangent to $y=f(x)$ at $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ and the tangent to $y=g(x)$ at $P_2(x_2,y_2)$, intersect at right angles at the point $Q(4,-1)$. Determine the coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

I know these derivatives: $f'(x)=-6x-14$, $g'(x)=x-\frac{15}{2}$

These two tangent lines intersect perpendicularly at point Q

I don't understand how to find the points $P_1$, and $P_2$.

Comment: Hint: Perpendicular lines have negative reciprocal slopes.

Comment: would i need to find the equation for each of the tangent lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative gives the slope of the tangent to the parabolas $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$. Plug in $x_1$ and $x_2$ to the derivatives and you will have the respective slopes of the tangent at points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$. Now since the slopes are perpendicular to each other $ (-6x_1 - 14) = \dfrac{-1}{ x_2 - \frac{15}{2}} ----- (1) $. Furthermore since $P_1Q \perp P_2Q$ we have that $ \dfrac{- 1 - y_1}{ 4 - x_1 } = (-1) \dfrac{4 - x_2}{ -1 - y_2 } ---(2)  $ where $y_1 = -3{x_1}^2-14x_1-5 $ and $ y_2 = (1/2){x_2}^2-(15/2)x_2+29 $. From here on you have two nasty equations in $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be solved. $y_1$ and $y_2$ can be obtained duly.

Comment: What equations would you use to solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @jasminder88: $(1)$ and $(2)$

Comment: okay, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

**nasty equations** yield P1=(-2,11), P2=(8,1).